# Aggregate multiple mysql table results to one

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a wordpress site that has a petition in it, I need to show all the petitioners by name, country and position.

But the wordpress theme I use is set up to store the values for the petition users in multiple rows (it seems wordpress always does this with users).

each user is stored as a WordPress user with the role of "petitioner". I managed to get all the petitioners using this query

```
SELECT display_name
     , meta_value
     , meta_key 
  FROM wp_users 
  JOIN wp_usermeta 
    ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
  WHERE meta_key = "petition_user_country" 
     OR meta_key = "petition_user_state" 
    AND meta_value !="" 
  ORDER 
     BY ID DESC;
```

This query now returns (only with test data)

```
+--------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| display_name             | meta_value | meta_key              |
+--------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
| Test3 Test34             | AF         | petition_user_country |
| Test3 Test34             | Tester     | petition_user_state   |
| Test Testnomsen          | NO         | petition_user_country |
| Test Testnomsen          | Student    | petition_user_state   |
| Brushan                  | NO         | petition_user_country |
| Kristian                 | Student    | petition_user_state   |
| Andreas Noe              | NO         | petition_user_country |
| Georg  Simone            | NO         | petition_user_country |
+--------------------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

The meta_value column holds both the position of the person and the country they are from. I need my HTML-table to show each person as one and display country, position and name.

Comment: The judicious use of parentheses would help. For further assistance, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use aggregation to get the data in single row for each entity and its different attributes

```
SELECT display_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'petition_user_country' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) country,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'petition_user_state'   THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) state,
FROM wp_users 
JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE meta_key IN('petition_user_country','petition_user_state')
  AND meta_value !="" 
GROUP BY display_name
ORDER BY display_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Join `wp_usermeta` twice and include the wanted `metakey` in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT display_name
     , wpumc.meta_value country
     , wpums.meta_value state
  FROM wp_users 
  JOIN wp_usermeta wpumc
    ON wp_users.ID = wpumc.user_id 
       AND wpumc.metakey = 'petition_user_country'
  JOIN wp_usermeta wpums
    ON wp_users.ID = wpums.user_id 
       AND wpums.metakey = 'petition_user_state'
  WHERE wpumc.meta_value !=""  
    AND wpums.meta_value !=""     
  ORDER 
     BY ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) :

```
SELECT display_name, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) AS meta_value,
       GROUP_CONCAT(meta_key) AS meta_value
FROM wp_users uw INNER JOIN 
     wp_usermeta um
     ON uw.ID = um.user_id 
WHERE meta_key IN ("petition_user_country", "petition_user_state") AND
      meta_value != "" 
GROUP BY display_name
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```